# form is not getting validated in django

Tags: python, django

my form is not returning data..
here is the code

views.py

```
 if request.method=="POST":
    add_gateway_details_form=Add_Gateway_Details(request.POST)
    add_gateway_parameters_form=Add_Gateway_Parameters(request.POST)
            if add_gateway_details_form.is_valid():
                   gateway_name=add_gateway_details_form.cleaned_data['gateway_name']
                   print gateway_name
            else:
                   add_gateway_details_form=Add_Gateway_Details()
            if add_gateway_parameters_form.is_valid():
                   gateway_param1=add_gateway_parameters_form.cleaned_data['gateway_param1']
                   print gateway_param1
                   gateway_param2=add_gateway_parameters_form.cleaned_data['gateway_param2']
                   print gateway_param2
           else:
                print "else"



  else:
    add_gateway_details_form=Add_Gateway_Details()
    add_gateway_parameters_form=Add_Gateway_Parameters()
```

when i am printing the data from add_gateway_parameters_form it's going in the else part but its working fine for add_gateway_details_form....(i am Not asking about validation)

Comment: Why do you re-instantiate the forms if they are not valid? That means your users will never see the errors.

Comment: i am not asking about validation....i am asking that i am not getting the data(i have edited the question....)

Comment: But it's going into the else part because the form is not valid. And you won't know why unless you return the validated form to the template, and show the errors there.

Comment: but the form is valid for gateway_details but not for gateway_parameters...

Comment: Yes, probably. So display the errors, then you'll know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
if add_gateway_parameters_form.is_valid():
      gateway_param1=add_gateway_parameters_form.cleaned_data['gateway_param1']
      print gateway_param1
      gateway_param2=add_gateway_parameters_form.cleaned_data['gateway_param2']
      print gateway_param2
else:
      print "else"
      #add_gateway_parameters_form=Add_Gateway_Parameters()
      #dont do this, rather just pass `add_gateway_parameters_form` to template

 ...
```

Don't reset form in `else` part and just pass the form to template and show form and form field errors in the template. With that you can see why its not validating.

Comment: i am not asking about validation....i am asking that i am not getting the data(i have edited the question....)